# Ansible combine list of items in single list

Tags: json, list, ansible

There is probably simple solution to this i just cant figure it out.
I got the following list in Ansible:

```
result: [
  {
    "name": "DC1",
    "region": "EU",
    "net": "10.10.1.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "DC1",
    "region": "EU",
    "net": "10.10.2.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "DC2",
    "region": "NA",
    "net": "10.10.3.0"
  },
]
```

and would like to get the new list in this format:

```
[
 {
    "name": "DC1",
    "region": "EU",
    "net": ["10.10.1.0","10.10.2.0"]
  },
 {
    "name": "DC2",
    "region": "NA",
    "net": "10.10.3.0"
  }
]
```

In the meantime i have also found the solution for the data format expected by Ansible module

```
- name: Convert items from the input list
  set_fact: 
    list_conv: "{{ list_conv|default([])+ (item | dict2items )}}"
  loop: "{{ result }}"
  when: item.name == 'DC1'

- name: Create new list 
  set_fact:
    list_final: "{{ list_final|default([]) + [{ item.key: item.value }]  }}"
  loop: "{{ list_conv | unique }}"
```

Output then will:

```
[
 {"name": "DC1"},
 {"region": "EU"},
 {"net": "10.10.1.0"},
 {"net": "10.10.2.0"}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more options.

1. The simplest option is converting the addresses to the lists

```yaml
  net_lists: "{{ result|json_query('[].{name: name, net: [net]}') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  net_lists:
    - name: DC1
      net: [10.10.1.0]
    - name: DC1
      net: [10.10.2.0]
    - name: DC2
      net: [10.10.3.0]
```

Then, merge the items by *name* and append the lists

```yaml
  net_list: "{{ [net_lists, []]|
                community.general.lists_mergeby('name', list_merge='append') }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  net_list:
    - name: DC1
      net: [10.10.1.0, 10.10.2.0]
    - name: DC2
      net: [10.10.3.0]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    result:
      - name: DC1
        net: 10.10.1.0
      - name: DC1
        net: 10.10.2.0
      - name: DC2
        net: 10.10.3.0

    net_lists: "{{ result|json_query('[].{name: name, net: [net]}') }}"
    net_list: "{{ [net_lists, []]|
                  community.general.lists_mergeby('name', list_merge='append') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: net_lists|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: net_list|to_yaml
```

---

2. The next option is grouping the items by *name*, selecting the keys and values, and creating a dictionary. Declare the variables

```yaml
  net_groups: "{{ result|groupby('name') }}"
  net_names: "{{ net_groups|map('first')|list }}"
  net_lists: "{{ net_groups|map('last')|
                            map('map', attribute='net')|list }}"
  net_dict: "{{ dict(net_names|zip(net_lists)) }}"
  net_list: "{{ net_dict|dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='net') }}"
```

give

```yaml
  net_groups:
    - - DC1
      - - {name: DC1, net: 10.10.1.0}
        - {name: DC1, net: 10.10.2.0}
    - - DC2
      - - {name: DC2, net: 10.10.3.0}
  net_names: [DC1, DC2]
  net_lists:
    - [10.10.1.0, 10.10.2.0]
    - [10.10.3.0]
  net_dict:
    DC1: [10.10.1.0, 10.10.2.0]
    DC2: [10.10.3.0]
  net_list:
    - name: DC1
      net: [10.10.1.0, 10.10.2.0]
    - name: DC2
      net: [10.10.3.0]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    result:
      - name: DC1
        net: 10.10.1.0
      - name: DC1
        net: 10.10.2.0
      - name: DC2
        net: 10.10.3.0

    net_groups: "{{ result|groupby('name') }}"
    net_names: "{{ net_groups|map('first')|list }}"
    net_lists: "{{ net_groups|map('last')|
                              map('map', attribute='net')|list }}"
    net_dict: "{{ dict(net_names|zip(net_lists)) }}"
    net_list: "{{ net_dict|dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='net') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: net_groups|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: net_names|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: net_lists|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: net_dict|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: net_list|to_yaml
```

Q: ***"How possibly can I generate such a list from my input data?"***

```yaml
- name: DC1
- net: 10.10.1.0
- net: 10.10.2.0
```

A: There are no filters to produce this structure. You can use Jinja instead. For example,

```yaml
  net_dict2_str: |
    {% for k,v in net_dict.items() %}
    {{ k }}:
      - name: {{ k }}
    {% for n in v %}
      - net: {{ n }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  net_dict2: "{{ net_dict2_str|from_yaml }}"
```

give

```yaml
  net_dict2:
    DC1:
    - name: DC1
    - net: 10.10.1.0
    - net: 10.10.2.0
    DC2:
    - name: DC2
    - net: 10.10.3.0
```

Fit the template to your needs.

Comment: this works great. 
but i actually made a mistake when looking at the result format. im dealing with F5 automation and for some reason the module expects following input format
 [
        {
            "name": "DC1"
        },
        {
            "net": "10.10.1.0"
        },
        {
            "net": "10.10.2.0"
        }
    ]
How possibly can i generate such list from my input data?

Comment: actually in the meantime i have found a way how to generate that F5 compatible list - i have added it above to my question

Comment: You can use Jinja. I added the example.